# When was any of Fontane's work first included in literary anthologies for use in schools?

Tags: history-of-literature, german-language, theodor-fontane

Theodor Fontane is now regarded as the most important German-language novelist of the second half of the nineteenth century. His work is now often required reading (German: ["Pflichtlektüre"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pflichtlekt%C3%BCre)) for secondary-school pupils. See for example [EFFI BRIEST. LANDESABITUR DEUTSCH. Pflichtlektüre](https://schule-studium.de/Deutsch/Landesabitur-Deutsch/Effi-Briest-Landesabitur-Inhaltlicher-Schwerpunkt.html), the article [Fontane-Jahr: Pflichtlektäre](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/kultur/fontane-jahr-1.4416087) in the *Suddeutsche Zeitung* of 19 April 2019 (paywalled article), Wilma R. Albrecht's [*Fontanes "Effi Briest". Wie kann man Schüler der Oberstufe für Pflichtlektüre begeistern?*](https://www.grin.com/document/109186) (GRIN Verlag, 2005) and [Was war eure Pflichtlektüre?](https://klassikerforum.de/forum/thread/16-was-war-eure-pflichtlekt%C3%BCre/) (Klassikerforum, 2002, in German).

How long has Fontane's work been regarded important enough to make it required reading for school pupils? I am looking for examples of Fontane's texts that were anthologised in German schoolbooks on literature. (I assume it would be harder to provide evidence for the first time any of his novels became required reading, so an anthology for use in schools is sufficient.)